# Access Ribbon in PowerPoint using interop

Tags: c#, interop

I'm wondering is it possible to access the ribbon and it buttons(elements) in PowerPoint using interop. I've searched online and all I can find is answers for if it's your own addin.

I thought I may have been able to access it like this but it's not what I'm looking for

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar bar in pptApp.CommandBars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Name + "   " + bar.Id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible!

Here is a MSDN walkthough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608593.aspx

Here is the list of all the existing Office controls (is also found in the MSDN walkthough): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627